# How to delete the closing tag of an element, add some text, and then add the tag back on?

Tags: javascript, html

The question is quite specific, but its for when an element (a div) has some text added to it in the form

```
<b>text</b>
```

I want to add new text to the div (appending), but would like to put it inside the last element within the div so:

```
<b>text</b>
```

becomes

```
<b>texttext2</b>
```

instead of having to do:

```
<b>text1</b><b>text2></b>
```

I have a

```
document.getElementById('div1');
```

and can append new text to it. But I would like to add it to the  element (which is always the last element in the div).

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Do you want to add any random text or a well-formated new tag? Like `<div sdgfdgd>` or like `<div class = "asdfgd">`?

Comment: clarified! Sorry after reading it back bit hasty

Comment: Are you also using jquery?

Comment: No just pure javascript

Comment: Check out `concat();` then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to do this:

```
var ele = document.querySelector("#div1 > b");
ele.innerHTML += "text2";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/PLpyt/

Note that if you have to support IE7 or before, you will have to do

```
var ele = document.getElementById('div1').getElementsByTagName("b")[0];
```

For course you can always use jQuery to support old browsers.

Comment: Hi, if I want to make it the last occurance of the B tag? http://jsfiddle.net/PLpyt/1/

Comment: `querySelector('#div1 :last-child')`

Comment: @OBV - For IE<=7: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/PLpyt/2/ For modern browsers: Use psquared's code posted in his comment. (`document.querySelector("#div1 >b:last-child")`)

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that will work everywhere, and with minimal code, consider:

```
var div = document.getElementById('div1');
div.lastChild.innerHTML += ' more text';
```

or even:

```
div.lastChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' more text'));
```

How many solutions do you need? :-)